# SEAM + HIBERNATE + jBPM - You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction

Tags: hibernate, seam, jbpm, autocommit

I'm using the hibernate SEAM, and now I started to learn jbpm. But I'm with this error:

```
12:11:47,222 ERROR [SchemaExport] schema export unsuccessful
java.sql.SQLException: You cannot set autocommit during a managed transaction!
            at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.BaseWrapperManagedConnection.setJdbcAutoCommit(BaseWrapperManagedConnection.java:598)
            at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection.setAutoCommit(WrappedConnection.java:458)
            at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:60)
            at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:252)
```

Should create a table called JBPM_PROCESSDEFINITION, but does not create.

**My configuration files are:**
hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
          "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
          "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="connection.datasource">java:/aerisDatasource</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="transaction.manager_lookup_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <!--property name="transaction.flush_before_completion">true</property-->

    <!-- ############################################ -->
    <!-- # mapping files with external dependencies # -->
    <!-- ############################################ -->

    <!-- following mapping file has a dependendy on   -->
    <!-- 'bsh-{version}.jar'.                         -->
    <!-- uncomment this if you don't have bsh on your -->
    <!-- classpath.  you won't be able to use the     -->
    <!-- script element in process definition files   -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/action/Script.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- following mapping files have a dependendy on  -->
    <!-- 'jbpm-identity.jar', mapping files            -->
    <!-- of the pluggable jbpm identity component.     -->
    <!-- Uncomment the following 3 lines if you        -->
    <!-- want to use the jBPM identity mgmgt           -->
    <!-- component.                                    -->
    <!-- identity mappings (begin) ===
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/identity/User.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/identity/Group.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/identity/Membership.hbm.xml"/>
    ==== identity mappings (end) -->

    <!-- following mapping files have a dependendy on  -->
    <!-- the JCR API                                   -->
    <!-- jcr mappings (begin) ===
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/JcrNodeInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    ==== jcr mappings (end) -->


    <!-- ###################### -->
    <!-- # jbpm mapping files # -->
    <!-- ###################### -->

    <!-- hql queries and type defs -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/db/hibernate.queries.hbm.xml" />

    <!-- graph.action mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/action/MailAction.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- graph.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/ProcessDefinition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Node.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Transition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Event.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/Action.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/SuperState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/def/ExceptionHandler.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/instantiation/Delegation.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- graph.node mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/StartState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/EndState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/ProcessState.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/Decision.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/Fork.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/Join.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/MailNode.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/State.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/node/TaskNode.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- context.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/def/ContextDefinition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/def/VariableAccess.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- taskmgmt.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/TaskMgmtDefinition.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/Swimlane.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/Task.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/def/TaskController.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- module.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/module/def/ModuleDefinition.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- bytes mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/bytes/ByteArray.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- file.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/file/def/FileDefinition.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- scheduler.def mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/scheduler/def/CreateTimerAction.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/scheduler/def/CancelTimerAction.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- graph.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/Comment.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/ProcessInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/Token.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/exe/RuntimeAction.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- module.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/module/exe/ModuleInstance.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- context.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/ContextInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/TokenVariableMap.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/VariableInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/ByteArrayInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/DateInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/DoubleInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/HibernateLongInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/HibernateStringInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/LongInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/NullInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/exe/variableinstance/StringInstance.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- job mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/Job.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/Timer.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/ExecuteNodeJob.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/job/ExecuteActionJob.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- taskmgmt.exe mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/TaskMgmtInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/TaskInstance.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/PooledActor.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/exe/SwimlaneInstance.hbm.xml"/>

    <!-- logging mapping files -->
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/logging/log/ProcessLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/logging/log/MessageLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/logging/log/CompositeLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ActionLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/NodeLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ProcessInstanceCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ProcessInstanceEndLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/ProcessStateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/SignalLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/TokenCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/TokenEndLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/graph/log/TransitionLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableDeleteLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/VariableUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/ByteArrayUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/DateUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/DoubleUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/HibernateLongUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/HibernateStringUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/LongUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/context/log/variableinstance/StringUpdateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskAssignLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/TaskEndLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/SwimlaneLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/SwimlaneCreateLog.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="org/jbpm/taskmgmt/log/SwimlaneAssignLog.hbm.xml"/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

jbpm.cfg.xml

```
<jbpm-configuration>
  <jbpm-context>
    <service name="persistence">
       <factory>
          <bean class="org.jbpm.persistence.db.DbPersistenceServiceFactory">
             <field name="isTransactionEnabled"><false/></field>
          </bean>
       </factory>
    </service>
    <service name="tx" factory="org.jbpm.tx.TxServiceFactory" />
    <service name="message" factory="org.jbpm.msg.db.DbMessageServiceFactory" />
    <service name="scheduler" factory="org.jbpm.scheduler.db.DbSchedulerServiceFactory" />
    <service name="logging" factory="org.jbpm.logging.db.DbLoggingServiceFactory" />
    <service name="authentication" factory="org.jbpm.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationServiceFactory" />
  </jbpm-context>
</jbpm-configuration>
```

Thank you